# Add new object to another object's object

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {}

obj.cats = {'name': 'Milo', 'age': 3} // first item

Object.assign(obj.cats, {'name': 'Simba', 'age': 2}) // add new item to obj.cats

console.log(obj) // result one item in obj.cats (Simba)
```

How can I add to the `obj.cats` here? All solutions I try they override `cats`

Wanted result:

```
obj {
 cats : {
     {'name': 'Milo', 'age': 3},
     {'name': 'Simba', 'age': 2}
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make an array?

Comment: An object has to have unique keys, so they will be overridden with the newer ones, what is your expected/wanted output?

Comment: are you saying that I have to add an array somewhere in the obj? I edited the question with what I want. Thx

Comment: Your expected result **is not a valid Javascript data structure**. You have two *values* in the obj.cats object, but no keys. Objects are collections of key-value-pairs, where the keys must be unique per-object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array of objects:

```js
var obj = {}

obj.cats = [{name: 'Milo', age: 3}] // first item

obj.cats.push({name: 'Simba', age: 2}) // add new item to obj.cats

console.log(obj) // result two items in obj.cats (Milo & Simba)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your wanted result is not valid, you can try with the object key:

```js
var obj = {}

obj.cats = {1:{'name': 'Milo', 'age': 3}} // first item

Object.assign(obj.cats, {2:{'name': 'Simba', 'age': 2}}) // add new item to obj.cats

console.log(obj) // result one item in obj.cats (Simba)
```